# (Perendev) Magnet motor with Superconducting shield

Tags: magnetic-fields, superconductivity, perpetual-motion

Can I get use a superconductor as a ‘shield’ to ‘focus’ the magnetic field analogous to water flow out of a pipe?

If yes then I could get a perendev magnet motor to work?

If not then why not?

As I understand it, the one variation of the prendev motor used a ferromagnetic shield.

This question relates to repeating it with a superconductor as a shield.

**References**:

1. https://youtu.be/Ooa8EBXKDW4
2. https://youtu.be/AWojYBhvfjM

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is impossible to understand the question without following the links.